# My selenium webdrivers will open for afew second, followed by chrome.exe unexpectedly exited

Tags: python, windows, selenium, pycharm, webautomation

I am trying to run a simple selenium program that will be able to open a website, but when I
enter code the chrome application will open for a few seconds followed my the terminal spitting out the error below. Here is the code I am inserting to pycharm.

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe')
```

Then this error text is given:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Billy Kimbell\!Coding!\Projects In Python\test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Billy Kimbell\!Coding!\Projects In Python\test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "C:\Users\Billy Kimbell\!Coding!\Projects In Python\test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated as I am exited to get started with this software.

Comment: Could you please check whether the version of chromedriver and chrome is same or not :)

Comment: you are trying to create a webdriver.Chrome instance with the location of chrome.  don't do that.  It is is expecting the location of chromedriver.exe instead.

Comment: Yes I have changes the location to an updates version of chrome.exe, Thanks for the help for anyone that has the same issue get that here:             https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem when all tools' version is right，the follow is my solution:

1. Go to selenium's folder and find directory of chrome ,my path is this:

   `D:\install\python3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome`
2. Edit options.py and add path of chrome.exe  to _binary_location of **init** like this：

```
    class Options(object):

        KEY = "goog:chromeOptions"
    
        def __init__(self):

            self._binary_location = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'   # add chrome path to webdriver
            self._arguments = []
            self._extension_files = []
            self._extensions = []
            self._experimental_options = {}
            self._debugger_address = None
            self._caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
```